# 16.04 will not use my 940M

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, graphics

I have an Asus UX303U that will not use my gpu.  I have updated and tried the drivers in additional hardware.  Nvidia X server still has no prime tab and nvidia-prime gives me command not found even though it is installed.  My intel gpu seems to just take over the entire time.  sudo apt-get purge nvidia-* does not find anything to purge.  I am not sure what to do.  Every guide I can find has a command that doesn't work or the option to switch to the nvidia gpu is not there.  Any ideas?

```
 lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics [8086:1916] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])

⇒  lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 07)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake Integrated Graphics
    Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM108M [GeForce 940M]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_364_drm, nvidia_364
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command. I do not see any Nvidia adapters.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Secure Boot in Bios, then run in terminal

```
sudo apt install nvidia-367 nvidia-prime
```

Then reboot.